# How to deal with downvotes without any explanation

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Sometimes there are bad questions that receive downvotes for different reasons.

The "Stackoverflow netiquette" says that, when downvoting, it's a good idea to explain the reasons in a comment, so the user can edit and improve the question.

The question is:

What is the user to do if she is receiving downvotes without any explanation? 
The reason of downvote can be obvious for the downvoter or the experienced users, but maybe it is not so obvious for the user who posed the question in the first place.

How can a user ask such a thing? Is there any protocol?

Comment: Related to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes.

Comment: It's funny ask a question about downvoting without commenting and receive a lot of downvotes without any comment. lol.

Comment: "How to deal with downvotes without any explanation?" - Therapy. Years and years of therapy.

Comment: Many people getting downvoted don't want to improve, but rather try to kill the messenger. That severely discourages downvoters from  revealing themselves.

Comment: Can you please express uour opinion on marking question as duplicate at the following link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219750/is-it-correct-to-mark-these-two-questions-as-a-duplicate

Comment: Sometimes, an answer challenges a user's world view enough that they react against it with a downvote. This is an indication that deep down, they agree, but cannot yet openly accept. In time they may return and upvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you see that a question is getting downvotes without explanations, and you happen to know what the downvotes *may* be about, leave a comment to point it out, e.g.

> Hi, you might be receiving downvotes because your post is poorly
>   edited. Please consider formatting it a little.

If you are the one who's post is being downvoted, there is nothing you really can do about it apart from moving on. There are, however, some things you might want to check:

- Is your question clear and concise? Some people may downvote questions that are too hard to understand because of poor phrasing.
- Is your question self-contained? Some people might downvote if the info given in the question is *obviously* not enough to answer. An example of this would be asking "whats wrong with my code?" and not posting the actual code.
- Is your question on-topic/constructive? (Consult the FAQ if you're not sure).
- Isn't your question offending anyone in some way (e.g. "Hey, I know you C++ programmers suck {insert some insults here} but nevertheless, answer this: ...").
- Is your question edited well? Some people may downvote questions that have poorly formatted code/walls of text/something else like this. I personally try to edit such posts myself (and I encourage everyone else to do it too), but some people might as well silently downvote.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe could be the first option, since English is not my native language.

Answer (score 13):

**Deal with it and move on.**

Voting is anonymous, while people are encouraged to post comments explaining their downvotes, no one is required to do so.

Comment: Two people upvoted this before me without even leaving a comment.

Comment: Maybe I don't explained well. The real problem is not the downvotes. The problem is how can I get an opinion of how improve a concrete question.

Comment: A suggestion : don't do [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000998/java-interface-does-not-allow-arraylist-to-function-correctly).

Comment: @user674887 If people care to give you their opinion on how to improve your question, they will (regardless of if they downvoted or not). If they don't care, they won't, and there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: If user have less then 2000 reputation They get [this message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gzdqj.png)

Comment: *Deal with it and move on*: very true, but downvotes can loose your privileges?

Comment: @ElCid So what?

Comment: @YannisRizos not a great incentive to participate, if one's new?

Comment: @ElCid Again, so what? You can't please everybody, people should participate on Stack Overflow because they want to help others, if downvotes scare them away, well, I'm not so sure that's a bad thing.

Comment: @YannisRizos: I'll give it a go. "So what?" How about the possible gentrification of the average SO user? People have to behave "in the same way" if they want to participate...

Comment: It should be made mandatory to leave a comment when downvoting, otherwise you shouldn't be allowed to leave a downvote.